# Cannot find module 'node-sass-middleware'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, gulp, node-sass

When trying to use gulp, I'm having ' Cannot find module 'node-sass-middleware' ' error.

```
module.js:340
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass-middleware'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/wallet/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/sass.js:180:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

node-sass-middleware is empty for some reason. 
I've installed gulp like

```
sudo npm install -g gulp
```

node-sass-middleware folder has appeared, but its empty inside but a node_modules folder which is also empty.

```
/home/wallet/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/node-sass-middleware/.js
```

Am I installing gulp wrong?

Comment: For some reason 

    sudo npm install gulp
did download empty gulp-util and node-sass folders so I installed them directly via

    sudo npm install gulp-util
    sudo npm install node-sass
and replaced folders in gulp-sass with two installed ones.
But I still don't understand why npm installed empty folders.

Comment: try installing gulp locally also

Comment: also you could install node-sass manually with npm install